# Shell script with single choice options

Tags: bash, shell, getopt, getopts

I'm wondering, if it is possible to write a shell script with options using    `getopt` or `getopts` that won't allow to combine multiple options?

E.g., my script could be ran in two possible modes - long or short and with alpha or beta options, that's why I would like to use `./script.sh -l -a` , `./script.sh -l -b` or `./script.sh -s -a` , `./script.sh -s -b`, but it shouldn't be possible to run both options `-l` and `-s` or `-a` and `-b` at the same time.

I know it can be made a lot easier, because I can make `option -a` which will run `long version alpha`, `option -b` which will run `long version beta`, `option -c` which will run `short version alpha`, and `option -d` which will run `short version beta`, but I want to use two options, just understand if such way is possible.

Please find below code with "options" to choose using simple `read`, what I want to convert into `getopt(s)`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please insert the text:"

read text 

echo

echo "You entered $text"

echo "Choose version:

1) Long
2) Short
3) Quit
-> "

read option

# OPTION 1 

if [ "$option" == "1" ]; then

echo "Choose method:

1) alpha
2) beta"

read method

# METHOD 1

if [ "$method" == "1" ]; then

longalpha

fi

# METHOD 2

if [ "$method" == "2" ]; then

longbeta

fi

fi

#OPTION 2

if [ "$option" == "2" ]; then

echo "Choose method:

1) alpha
2) beta"

read method2

# METHOD 1

if [ "$method2" == "1" ]; then

shortalpha

fi

# METHOD 2

if [ "$method2" == "2" ]; then

shortbeta

fi

fi

if [ "$option" == "3" ]; then

echo "Good Bye!"

fi
```

Comment: Is it necessary that either `-l` or `-s` be present, and should they both be the first parameter if used?

Comment: Either of them have to present, and it doesn't matter if it is the first parameter used or not. The script should not work while there is only `-l` or `-s` an option, there must be `-l -a` / `-l -b` / `-s -a` / `-s -b`.

As far as I know (I'm just starting my journey with shell scirpting), `getopt` or `getopts` run separate options in a code one by one, but I want to run script1 if there is `-l -a`, script 2 if there is `-l -b`, script 3 if there is `-s -a`, script 4 if there is `-s -b`

Comment: @KoahNuttler: Does the order matter? is `-a -l` invalid? just for a confirmation

Comment: @Inian: It doesn't it just tells if the script should run another shorter script or longer script: longer version of script a, shorter version of script a etc.

Comment: Are you, then, looking for a solution purely in `getopt(s)`?  It wouldn't be good enough to set the `long` flag with `-l` and the `short` flag with `-s` and after processing all the arguments check if both flags are set and complain?

Comment: @Eric Renouf: I'm not focused only on getopt(s), I was thiking if any other solutions would fit there as well. What matters for me is: `if ./script.sh -l -a then...`, `if script.sh -s -b` then... and I need to use one more option with argument at the end, which is  necessary (that's why I thought of getopt(s))

Comment: @KoahNuttler  You should put the code of your script (your attempt, even if it does not work)

Comment: @Fred since I'm a beginner, my script currently is something like 4 pages long (echoes options, reads the input), but I will do my best to make it shorter and paste it here

Comment: @KoahNuttler Include in your post the part that is related to options handling, which is what your question is about.

Comment: @Fred, please find in my edited question part of the code referring to my current options setup

Comment: I am a little puzzled...  You are asking about getopts, but your script is interactive with read statements.  Do you want a command line utility, or an interactive program?

Comment: @Fred my script at the moment looks like above, but I want to change it to specify the options while executing the script instead of choosing them one by one in the command line

Answer (score 1):

You should parse all the options first, and set variables indicating which have been passed and which have not.

Then, before actually executing anything, test if `-l` and `-s` are both present or both missing, and if so exit with the appropriate error message.

You can perform a similar check with `-a` and `-b`

Once you know you have everything that is needed, but nothing more, then you can have your script perform the appropriate operation.

Comment: It would be useful to show us in code, how you can do it. In its current form it is just a _comment_

Comment: The OP's problem does not seem to be how to write working code (there is no code, working or not working, in the question, so that makes providing pertinent example code difficult), the problem seems to be identifying the right approach to code the desired behavior.  This is why I described an idea rather than writing actual code.

Comment: Just to be clear what I mean, it might make for a better answer to provide code the OP can copy and paste by SO standards, but in the case where the question is about a logical approach to a desired result, suggesting an approach without code can, in my opinion, constitute an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @KoahNuttler  Please put your code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

When running `getopts` you can check if an exclusive flag has already been set by having *un*set variables representing that flag.

Let's say you have two variables that will determine what you want to do, and they start unset:

```
unset vers meth
```

And you also have a lookup table for flags to actions, like:

```
declare -A flags=([l]=long [s]=short [a]=alpha [b]=beta)
```

Then you can run `getopts` like:

```
while getopts "lsab" opt; do
    case $opt in
        (l|s) [[ $vers ]] && fail       # we already set $vers
              vers=${flags[$opt]} ;;
        (a|b) [[ $meth ]] && fail       # we already set $meth
              meth=${flags[$opt]} ;;
        ('?') fail ;;                   # we got some unknown option
    esac
done
```

The only thing that remains is to check that we did get *something* for `$vers` and `$meth`:

```
[[ $vers && meth ]] || fail
```

And then execute your task:

```
$vers$method
```

<sup>The way you handle this last part depends on the specifics of your code, but since you are calling `shortalpha`, etc., this way fits well.  If you are instead calling some external code, this might be like `prog --$vers --$meth`, etc.</sup>